# Why dont I get the alert message when i click the sign up button?

Tags: javascript

When i click the Sign up button, I dont get the alert message. Other alerts show the output perfectly. But I think there is problem in the else statement. I want to show the alert message when any user click the Sign up button.

```
function check(form) {
    name = form.name.value;
    mobile = form.mobile.value;
    age = form.age.value;
    email = form.email.value;
    password = form.password.value;
    conpassword = form.conpassword.value;

    if(name==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Name",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(mobile==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Mobile Number",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(age==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Age",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(email==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter E-mail",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(password==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Password",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(conpassword==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Confirm Password",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(password!=conpassword){
        swal({
              title: "",ant
              text: "Password Did Not Match",
              icon: "error",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else{
        swal({
              title: "Thank You!",
              text: "Now you can access",
              icon: "success",
            });
       return true; 
    }
}
```

I use [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/) (`swal()`)

Comment: What does the function call looks like?

Comment: @Snickbrack

see my  html code:
`<form onsubmit="return check(this)" action="#" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="name" >
     <input type="text" name="mobile" 
     <input type="text" name="age" >
     <input type="text" name="email" >
     <input type="password" name="password">
     <input type="password" name="conpassword" >
     <input type="submit"  value="Sign Up">
     <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
    </form>
`

Comment: please always put code into the question itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html one  **is wrong and in

javascript ,ant** after title is cause error

```
else if(password!=conpassword){
    swal({
          title: "",ant/*wrong*/
          text: "Password Did Not Match",
          icon: "error",
        });
    return false;
}
```

```js
function check(form) {
    name = form.name.value;
    mobile = form.mobile.value;
    age = form.age.value;
    email = form.email.value;
    password = form.password.value;
    conpassword = form.conpassword.value;

    if(name==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Name",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(mobile==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Mobile Number",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(age==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Age",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(email==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter E-mail",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(password==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Password",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(conpassword==''){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field!",
              text: "Enter Confirm Password",
              icon: "warning",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else if(password!=conpassword){
        swal({
              title: "Empty Field",
              text: "Password Did Not Match",
              icon: "error",
            });
        return false;
    }

    else{
        swal({
              title: "Thank You!",
              text: "Now you can access",
              icon: "success",
            });
       return true; 
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return check(this)" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" > 
  <input type="text" name="mobile">
  <input type="text" name="age" >
  <input type="text" name="email" >
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="password" name="conpassword" >
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"> <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You. but in my brower(Chrome & Mozilla ) dont show the alert message when i click the Sign up button.